# pgfplots: relative node positioning in axis cs

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, nodes

I have got a file to plot with pgfplots. For convenience I'd like to define a measure in the plot. Unfortunately the relative positioning seems to give weird results. If I define the node coordinates manually everything works fine. According to the `pgfplots`-manual the sin- and cos-operators use degrees. Could you please tell me where my error is?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{cellmodel/.style={%
width=0.4\linewidth,
height=0.3\textheight,
axis lines=center,
axis equal image,
domain=0:800,
xmin= 0, xmax= 7,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=6.5,
restrict x to domain=0:7,
ticks=none,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{-30}
\begin{axis}[cellmodel]
\addplot[mark=x, mark options={solid}, draw=gray!80!black, dashed, thick] coordinates { 
        (0.0,0.5)
        (2.25,0.5)
        (4.5,4.397114317029974)
        (6.75,4.397114317029974)
};

% necessary nodes
\node (two) at (axis cs:2.25,0.5) {};
\node (thr) at (axis cs:4.5,4.397114317029974) {};

% relative nodes
% \node (mes2l)  at ($(two)+({cos(\angle)},{sin(\angle)})$) {test};     % <- doesn't give the correct coordinates
% \node (mes3l)  at ({$(thr)+({cos(\angle)},{sin(\angle)})$}) {test};
% \node (mes2l)  at ($(two)+(axis cs:{cos(\angle)},{sin(\angle)})$) {test};     % <- doesn't give the correct coordinates
% \node (mes3l)  at ({$(thr)+(axis cs:{cos(\angle)},{sin(\angle)})$}) {test};
\node (mes2l)  at (axis cs:3.116025404,0) {};                   % <- correct coordinates
\node (mes3l)  at (axis cs:5.366025404,3.897114317) {};
\draw[<->]  (mes2l.center) -- (mes3l.center) node [below right, midway]{$l$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you expect that adding a positive quantity `sin 30` to `0.5` would result in a `y=0`?  You have `\node (two) at (axis cs:2.25,0.5)` and `\node (mes2l)  at ($(two)+(axis cs:{cos(30)},{sin(30)})$)`.

Comment: And where exactly should the new nodes be located? Where exactly are you trying to place those additional nodes?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina If you compile the code as it is, I think you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Of course it must be `-30°`. This must have been switched around during all the trial and error runs.

Comment: @PeterGrill what does the cs:2.25,0.5 represent?

Comment: @NickB: I think in the older versions, one had to specify the coordinate system, but now that is the default so no need to specufy 'cs:' anymore with a more recent `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might be easiest to just move the definition of the `mes21` and `mes31` nodes outside the `axis`, then they use the coordinate system of the `tikzpicture` rather than the `axis`. (I changed the angle to `-30`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{cellmodel/.style={%
width=0.4\linewidth,
height=0.3\textheight,
axis lines=center,
axis equal image,
domain=0:800,
xmin= 0, xmax= 7,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=6.5,
restrict x to domain=0:7,
ticks=none,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{-30}
\begin{axis}[cellmodel]
\addplot[mark=x, mark options={solid}, draw=gray!80!black, dashed, thick] coordinates { 
        (0.0,0.5)
        (2.25,0.5)
        (4.5,4.397114317029974)
        (6.75,4.397114317029974)
};

% necessary nodes
\coordinate (two) at (axis cs:2.25,0.5) {};
\coordinate (thr) at (axis cs:4.5,4.397114317029974) {};
\end{axis}

\def\scaling{0.4}
\coordinate (mes2l)  at ($(two)+\scaling*({cos(\angle)},{sin(\angle)})$);
\coordinate (mes3l)  at ($(thr)+\scaling*({cos(\angle)},{sin(\angle)})$);
\draw[<->]  (mes2l) -- (mes3l) node [below right, midway]{$l$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does what I want for my example. But is there also a way to calculate node positions relative to another node inside the axis environment? One may need this for future use, if the axis scaling is of importance

Comment: @krtek I don't know of any good ways, but I don't know the details of how this work. You could use something like `\coordinate (mes2l)  at ($(two)+({400*cos(\angle)},{50*sin(\angle)})$) {};
\coordinate (mes3l)  at ($(thr)+({400*cos(\angle)},{50*sin(\angle)})$) {};`, but it is not very convenient.

Comment: ok. By the way, thanks for the reminder, that `\coordinate` is sufficient here instead of `\node`

Comment: @krtek Hopefully you'll get a better answer later.

Comment: Well, I accepted your answer anyway, since it solves my problem at the moment :)

Answer (score 2):

just small variation on @Torbjørn T. solution:

```
    \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
        \usepackage{siunitx}

    \pgfplotsset{cellmodel/.style={%
        width=0.4\linewidth,
        height=0.3\textheight,
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal image,
        domain=0:800,
        xmin= 0, xmax= 7,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=6.5,
        restrict x to domain=0:7,
        ticks=none,
    }}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[cellmodel]
    \addplot[mark=x, mark options={solid}, draw=gray!80!black, dashed, thick] 
        coordinates {
            (0.0,0.5)
            (2.25,0.5)
            (4.5,4.397114317029974)
            (6.75,4.397114317029974)
                    };
    % necessary nodes
    \coordinate (two) at (axis cs:2.25,0.5) {};
    \coordinate (thr) at (axis cs:4.5,4.397114317029974) {};
    \end{axis}
    \draw[transform canvas={shift={(-30:0.3)}},<->]  
        (two) to node[right] {$l$}    (thr);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

mybe it will help so